# Disable pinned tabs being in every window in Safari 9

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

Is there any way to disable pinned tabs showing up in every Safari window? I typically have several Spaces going and the pinned tabs are only relevant to those spaces or even just to the specific Safari window.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's the design intent of pinned tabs. They are pinned to the app and not a window / document.

If you don't wish to have the tabs shown in all windows but still want easy access, bookmark many tabs with shift-command-D and you can open them with a single click.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135696/discussion-on-answer-by-grg-disable-pinned-tabs-being-in-every-window-in-safari).

Answer (score 2):

You can open a new private window and those will be gone

Comment: Unfortunately, that also means any history/cookies/etc will not be saved when I visit a site again. Also, each tab is separate from the others in a private window, so if I log into a site in one tab, I won't be logged into the site in a new tab. Not really a good solution.

Answer (score -2):

Ok so MY take on why a pinned tab shouldn't show up in every window is this:

- a "pinned" tab means that when I start the browser from scratch, that FIRST window opens with my pinned tabs. Every subsequent window I open is just a blank window. I may even drag a tab out to create a new window... that doesn't mean I want my pinned tabs in the new window.
- I don't think it's good design to open multiple instances of the same tab every time a window is open. A lot of people (myself included) compartmentalize different goals with sets of tabs in windows. i.e. Development window might have tabs like SO; AWS console; Cloud9; etc, while social may have gmail (pinned); twitter; FB; reddit; etc.
- Chrome runs a separate process for each tab, with the intention that 1 bad tab doesn't bring down the whole application. Not sure if Safari treats it the same way (webkit right?), but if it does then multiple copies of the same pinned tab seems wasteful.
- If I have 3 windows open, each with a pinned Gmail tab, I should be able to close 2 of them and keep the 1 pinned tab on the social/comm window. However, current behavior is that closing the pinned tab on 1 window closes it on all windows.

So, am I right? I am to me, and probably others who view pinned tabs the same way, but that doesn't make me right for everybody. I think this could be an option/preference item going forward to help us all enjoy a peaceful coexistence ;)

Somebody asked for an expansion of this view beyond "it's really not", so this is my take.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't really fit the format of a StackExchange site - it's more commentary than an answer.